# How to forward unnamed function arguments

Tags: c++, c++17

So, I'm trying to create a mocking-macro for my virtual class functions.

This is a example of a mocked class with one mock function. (This works as expected)

```cpp
class MockEnvironment : public IEnvironment {
public:
    using runType = int(std::string program,
                        std::vector<std::string> arguments);

    MockedFunction<runType> runMock = MockedFunction<runType>("run");

    int run(std::string program, std::vector<std::string> arguments) override {
        return runMock(program, arguments);
    }

    //    MOCK_METHOD(int, run, (std::string, std::vector<std::string>)); // this is the goal
};
```

`MockedFunction` is a class with a operator() that is supposed to be called whenever the function is called.

My goal is to wrap the function in a macro, to be able to mock any function. The problem as you might see is that when generalizing, i would need to handle a function with unnamed arguments.

```cpp
#define MOCK_METHOD(ret, name, args)                                           \
    MockedFunction<ret(args)> mocked_##name =                                  \
        MockedFunction<ret(args)>(#name);                                      \
    ret name##Mock(args) { /* how to solve? */ }

// This would expand to something like
MockedFunction<...> runMock = MockedFunction<...>("run"); // More detailed in above example

int run(std::string, std::vector<std::string>) override {
    return runMock(/*how to forward the arguments when they do not have names?*/)
}
```

I have thought of using some kind of varadic template, but I haven't found any way to make it work. I have also tried to read googles mock-implementation, but i find it hard to see how they have solved it.

So my question is simply. How do i move the content of the arguments in `run` to the function to be called?

It is ok for me to use up to c++17. I do realize that it would be easier if you specify in the macro how many arguments you need, but it would be optimal if it would be possible to solve for the more general example.

Edit:
This is the best i have come up with if i know the number of arguments in beforehand.

```cpp
#define INTERNAL_MOCK_METHOD_COMMON(ret, name, args)                           \
    using name##T = ret(args);                                                 \
    unittest::MockedFunction<ret(args)> mock_##name =                          \
        unittest::MockedFunction<ret(args)>(#name);

#define MOCK_METHOD(ret, name)                                                 \
    INTERNAL_MOCK_METHOD_COMMON(ret, name, ())                                 \
    ret name() {                                                               \
        return mock_##name();                                                  \
    }

#define MOCK_METHOD1(ret, name, args)                                          \
    INTERNAL_MOCK_METHOD_COMMON(ret, name, args)                               \
    ret name(typename unittest::MockedFunction<name##T>::ArgT<0>::type a) {    \
        return mock_##name(a);                                                 \
    }

#define MOCK_METHOD2(ret, name, args)                                          \
    INTERNAL_MOCK_METHOD_COMMON(ret, name, args)                               \
    ret name(typename unittest::MockedFunction<name##T>::ArgT<0>::type a,      \
             typename unittest::MockedFunction<name##T>::ArgT<1>::type b) {    \
        return mock_##name(a, b);                                              \
    }

// ...

template <typename T>
class MockedFunction {};

template <typename ReturnT, typename... ArgsT>
class MockedFunction<ReturnT(ArgsT...)> {
public:
    // Return argument type at the specified index
    template <int i>
    struct ArgT {
        using type = typename std::tuple_element_t<i, std::tuple<ArgsT...>>;
    };
```

Then it is possible to use like this

```cpp
class IObject {
public:
    virtual int update() = 0;
    virtual void setValue(int) = 0;
};

class MockObject : public IObject {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(int, update);
    MOCK_METHOD1(void, setValue, (int));
};
```

To be clear: It would be nice to not have to specify the numbers of arguments with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use unnamed arguments. You might consider naming them, perhaps like this:

```
#define MOCK_METHOD(ret, name, args, names)                                           \
    MockedFunction<ret(args)> mocked_##name =                                  \
        MockedFunction<ret(args)>(#name);                                      \
    ret name##Mock(args) { return runMock names; }

MOCK_METHOD(int, run, (std::string s, std::vector<std::string> v), (s, v));
```

Comment: It would be nice, but i do not think that you can override the parent class' non template function with a template function (that is required if you want to mock it)

Comment: Then you might consider generating argument names using the preprocessor. See for example how Google Mock does it:https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/356f2d264a485db2fcc50ec1c672e0d37b6cb39b/googlemock/include/gmock/gmock-function-mocker.h#L138

Comment: Interesting. I thought that you needed to specify the number of arguments with google mock, but maybe i just used a old version of google mock. I have a hard time to se how it works. If you help me with a example that I can use to understand it i will accept that answer.

Comment: Indeed, `MOCK_METHOD` was added in the latest version of Google Test. It works with a macro similar to `BOOST_PP_LIST_FOR_EACH_I` (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/list_for_each_i.html).

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#define identity(...) __VA_ARGS__

#define MOCK_METHOD(ret, name, params, args)                                           \
    MockedFunction<ret identity(params)> mocked_##name =                                  \
        MockedFunction<ret identity(params)>(#name);                                      \
    ret name##Mock(identity params) { return name args; }
```

is this what you want? it's allowed to name the parameters in a declaration of function type.

Comment: So how does this work? Do you need to spell out the names in the args-parameter?

Comment: if my understanding is correct, what you want is declaring a delegate class to do something and then call the original function. so just declare the parameters at `params`, and give the arguments at `args`. in fact, you can write any code at `args`, such as `(int a, int b)` at `params`, and `(a+b)` at `args`, which means to receive 2 int and call the function `run` by argument `a+b`.